# FatalExecutionEngineError on OGRE3D Window Close

Tags: c#, window, sfml, ogre3d, ogre

I'm using MOGRE, a C# binding of OGRE3D. I've created my own rendering loop and I use WindowEventUtilities.MessagePump() to update the window.

This is my main application loop:

```
while (SFMLWin.IsOpened() && !OGREWin.IsClosed)
{
    try
    {
        if (fpsClock.Milliseconds > 0)
            fps = 1000 / fpsClock.Milliseconds;

        fpsClock.Reset();
        SFMLWin.DispatchEvents();
        SFMLWin.GetFrameTime();
        inputKeyboard.Capture();
        inputMouse.Capture();
        OnCollision();
        OnKeyHold();
        MainDraw();
        WindowEventUtilities.MessagePump();
    }
    catch
    {
        break;
    }
}
SFMLWin.Dispose();
OGREWin.Dispose();
```

I am still getting the "FatalExecutionError" code when I close OGREWin at WindowEventUtilities.MessagePump();. The try/catch statement doesn't catch anything, and I can't implement any if statements around WindowEventUtilities.MessagePump() to fix the situation. I am really stumped on what to do.

I've posted a topic on the MOGRE boards, but have not yet found a solution.

Comment: The native code is corrupting the garbage collected heap.  Possibly due to a bad pinvoke declaration, but you'll have a heck of a time finding it.  The place where it crashes is not the place where the damage is done.  It is not a catchable exception in .NET 4, it is too severe a heart attack.  Cut your losses if you can't get help from the authors.

Comment: Check your ogre log. If there are ogre exceptions it sometimes puts a hint there